# My code doesn't take input of character in online c compiler "programiz.com"

Tags: c

My code doesn't take the input of a character in on online C compiler at "programiz.com".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    float b;
    char ch;
    char str[100];
    
    printf("Enter an integer : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    
    printf("Enter a decimal number : ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    
    printf("Enter a character : ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    
    printf("Enter a string : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
}
```

It directly jumps from taking decimal input to string, and I don't know why.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer to it, but puting "Enter a character" before the other inputs would work.

Comment: Use `" %c"` to skip the newline left behind by the previous scan for a number.  See the duplicate for more details.